# How can I print all arguments passed to a python script?

Tags: python

How can I print all arguments passed to a python script?

This is what I was trying:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print(sys.argv[1:]);
```

**update**

How can I save them to a file?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
print sys.argv[1:]
file = open("/tmp/test.txt", "w")
file.write(sys.argv[1:])
```

I get

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Comment: Instead of saying "this does not work", take time to find out *why* it "doesn't work". This includes things like reading -- *and posting* -- the error messages/symptoms.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You'll need to `import sys` for that to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
print  sys.argv[1:]
```

---

**Example**

```
:/tmp% cat foo.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
print (sys.argv[1:]);

:/tmp% python foo.py 'hello world' arg3 arg4 arg5
['hello world', 'arg3', 'arg4', 'arg5']
```

Answer (score 5):

the problem is with the list of args that write can't handle.

You might want to use:

```
file.write('\n'.join(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Answer (score 4):

Your last line is wrong.

It should be:

```
file.writelines(sys.argv[1:])
```