# Print all argparse arguments including defaults

Tags: python, logging, namespaces, argparse, sys

I want to log the usage of a python program which uses the argparse module.  Currently, the logger records the command line usage similar to the answer given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542725/how-can-i-print-all-arguments-passed-to-a-python-script).  However, that only gives the command line arguments, and not including the defaults set later in argparse (which is the intended use, after all).  Is there a simple way to print ALL the argparse options to create a nice, tidy `usage` log entry that includes the default values?

It isn't difficult to go into the argparse namespace to fetch each argument by name, but I am hoping that someone has a concise way of extracting the needed info.

In response to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39978305/7758804):

Great! If anyone is interest, here is my implementation with logging:

```
logger.info("Usage:\n{0}\n".format(" ".join([x for x in sys.argv])))
logger.debug("All settings used:") for k,v in sorted(vars(args).items()):
    logger.debug("{0}: {1}".format(k,v))
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've done something similar in an application, hopefully the below snippets give you what you need. It is the call to vars that gave me a dictionary of all the arguments.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Configure')
....
args = parser.parse_args()
......
options = vars(args)
```