# How to specify difftool_args for git-difftool?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I am trying to use a custom diff tool for git diff. The following command does the job:

```
git difftool --tool nbdime "file.ipynb"
```

This starts up a diff viewer on the web, with the following arguments:

```
{'difftool_args' : {'base': '/tmp/ZpUu2a_1 - file.ipynb',
                    'remote': 'file.ipynb'},
                    'port': 0,
                    'cwd': '/home/user/Projects/prj2'}
```

However, I need to specify the port for my difftool nbdime

I tried the following (+ other permutations):

```
git difftool --tool nbdime --port 5555 "file.ipynb"
```

but none get accepted as an argument *to* the difftool; so how would one provide an argument to the difftool?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [**`nbdime`** (Tools for diffing and merging of Jupyter notebooks.)](https://github.com/jupyter/nbdime), since it does take a [-p argument](https://github.com/jupyter/nbdime/pull/55/files), I would wrap that in a script, which would:

- [get all parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8542731/6309)
- call `nbdime` with those paramters and the port

Actually, that script exists: [`nbdime/webapp/nbdifftool.py`](https://github.com/jupyter/nbdime/blob/master/nbdime/webapp/nbdifftool.py)

I would then use that script in the `git difftool --tool` directive (without the port, since said port is set within the wrapper script)